# Show height change in real time

Tags: jquery, css, real-time

I just wrote a script that returns a div's height compared to it's parent into percentage.

I just need to find a way to display that height change in real time while animating the change.

This is what I have so far:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/ehf6e3u0/1/)

JS:

```
var full = $('#wrap').height();
var value = $('#bla').height();
var percentage = value*100/full ;

$('h1').html( percentage + '%');

$('#bla').delay(1500).animate({
    height: '74%'
},2200, "easeOutElastic");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/ehf6e3u0/3/)

you can set an interval which looks for the height of the div and update the text accordingly

```
var inter=setInterval(function(){
    var full = $('#wrap').height();
    var value = $('#bla').height();
    var percentage = value*100/full ;
    $('h1').html( percentage + '%');
},10)
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't think about this approach...setting an interval to run the search every 10 milliseconds...Well, it's working. :) Thank you :) (+1 for now, can't accept just yet)

Answer (score 0):

Try using $('#bla').innerHeight();
You can get changing height of the div including padding also.

Comment: I am not using innerHeight or outerHeight exactly cause I don't want it to take the padding or margin. Thanks.